# Best way to remove file extension from a string?

Tags: shell, filenames

So, I'm using a script I've made to convert videos to the webm format. A certain program calls the script, sending `%f` which is the full, absolute file name of the video, like this:

```
converter.sh %f
```

where `%f` has two possible extensions, `.avi` or `.mpg`.

```
# /bin/bash
ffmpeg -i $1 `dirname $1``basename $1 avi`webm && rm $1
```

It currently works perfectly when `$1` contains a `.avi` file, because `basename` removes the `.avi` extension. When `$1` ends with `.mpg` instead, the result is `.mpgwebm`.

How can I modify that script to be able to receive those two possible different formats?

---

Resuming: If `$1` is `/somedir/video.avi`, the script should do:

```
ffmpeg -i /somedir/video.avi /somedir/video.webm
```

And if `$1` is `/somedir/video.mpg`, the script should do:

```
ffmpeg -i /somedir/video.mpg /somedir/video.webm
```

I know this might be fool for some people, but I'm kind of new with the bash.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use substitution mechanisms provided by most shells:

```
B=$(basename "$1"); D=$(dirname "$1");
ffmpeg -i "$1" "$D/${B%.*}.webm" && rm "$1"
```

In fact, `basename` and `dirname` could also be emulated by substitutions.

Note: direct `.*` suffix removal is not correct on paths like `this.dir/file`.

Comment: I allowed myself to quote the variable and to replace backquotes by `$(…)`

Comment: Yes, but the files would be named `*.avi.webm` or `*.mpg.webm` because `basename` doesn't remove the extension unless you specify it after.

Comment: Sorry, my first answer was stupid! Edited and still need improvement.

Comment: Thanks, it's much better now. I didn't know about those substitution mechanisms. I don't think there is a better way. Using `sed` is a headache.

Comment: One question: Why should I use `"$1"` instead of just `$1`?

Comment: @Tomas: Without quotes and in the case your filenames contain spaces, they would be split into several paths.

Comment: Why use `dirname`, `basename` and not to use directly `ffmpeg -i "$1" "${1%.*}.webm" && rm "$1"

Comment: Also, `D=$(dirname "$1")` will change all multispace sequences to a single space, without quotes around `$()`.

Comment: @enzotib: The note is there to avoid precisely this question! And word spitting is meaningless for variable assignations. I wish I could downvote your comments :-)

Comment: Ehm, sorry, you are perfectly right.