# getting file name from the input path to the file in shell scripts

Tags: shell-script, scripting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Best way to remove file extension from a string?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18765/best-way-to-remove-file-extension-from-a-string)

Say that I have a script called `script.sh`

In the shell I type

```
script.sh ../folder/file.py
```

and in that file I know `echo $1` will output `../folder/file.py`

But is there anyway of getting just the filename without the extension... `file` only?

Answer (score 2):

BASH has a number of [string operators](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html) you might want to use here, but I don't see how to do it in just one, so you can either use two statements, or a subshell:

```
echo `basename ${1%.py}`
```

Or, more generally,

```
echo `basename ${1%.*}`
```

Or, with a temporary variable:

```
FILE=${1##*/}
echo ${FILE%.*}
```

I suppose, as long as you're using a subshell, `sed` will work too.

```
echo `echo $1 | sed 's/.*\/\([^/]*\)\(\.[^./]*\)\?/\1/'`
```

That's a somewhat ugly expression, but it could be cleaned up if you made some assumptions about the input.

Comment: Your `sed` substitution not works for me. For “../folder/file.py” returns “f.py”.

Comment: Sorry, I tested it on a single letter file name. Corrected it

Answer (score 0):

if your extension is always delimited by the point and filenames does not have point(s) inthere, you could use the simple way :

```
echo $(basename $1) | cut -d. -f1
```

But definitly the best way is the one described above by Kevin.

Comment: That `cut` has no chance with file names like “M.C. Hammer - U Can't Touch This.txt”.